# virtualenvwrapper issues on cygwin using python3.4 (installed using standalone installer)

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper

I'm having issues with virtualenv wrapper, I receive the below error when I run: 
source /cygdrive/c/Python34/Scripts/virtualenvwrapper.sh

I've run

- which python <- shows correct path
- which virtualenvwrapper.sh <- shows correct path
- which virtualenv <- shows correct path

Error:

```
>$ source /cygdrive/c/Python34/Scripts/virtualenvwrapper.sh
stevedore.extension error calling 'project': [Errno 2] No such file or directory                                          : 'C:\\home\\kolafsson\\.virtualenvs\\premkproject'
stevedore.extension [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\home\\kolafsson\\.                                          virtualenvs\\premkproject'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\stevedore-0.15-py3.4.egg\stevedore\extensi                                          on.py", line 248, in _invoke_one_plugin
    response_callback(func(e, *args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\virtualenvwrapper-4.2-py3.4.egg\virtualenv                                          wrapper\hook_loader.py", line 185, in invoke
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\virtualenvwrapper-4.2-py3.4.egg\virtualenv                                          wrapper\project.py", line 30, in initialize
    comment)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\virtualenvwrapper-4.2-py3.4.egg\virtualenv                                          wrapper\user_scripts.py", line 124, in make_hook
    f = open(filename, 'w')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\home\\kolafsson\\.v                                          irtualenvs\\premkproject'
stevedore.extension error calling 'user_scripts': [Errno 2] No such file or dire                                          ctory: 'C:\\home\\kolafsson\\.virtualenvs\\initialize'
stevedore.extension [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\home\\kolafsson\\.                                          virtualenvs\\initialize'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\stevedore-0.15-py3.4.egg\stevedore\extensi                                          on.py", line 248, in _invoke_one_plugin
    response_callback(func(e, *args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\virtualenvwrapper-4.2-py3.4.egg\virtualenv                                          wrapper\hook_loader.py", line 185, in invoke
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\virtualenvwrapper-4.2-py3.4.egg\virtualenv                                          wrapper\user_scripts.py", line 141, in initialize
    make_hook(get_path('$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR', filename), comment)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\virtualenvwrapper-4.2-py3.4.egg\virtualenv                                          wrapper\user_scripts.py", line 124, in make_hook
    f = open(filename, 'w')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\home\\kolafsson\\.v                                          irtualenvs\\initialize'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 171, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\virtualenvwrapper-4.2-py3.4.egg\virtualenv                                          wrapper\hook_loader.py", line 217, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\virtualenvwrapper-4.2-py3.4.egg\virtualenv                                          wrapper\hook_loader.py", line 137, in main
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/virtualenvwrapper-                                          initialize-hook-Kxjb02CrwN'
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.
```

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenv has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/cygdrive/c/Python34/python and that PATH is
set properly.

Does anyone know what is causing this error and how I could fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Problems I had were due to the permissions on the virtualenv directory not being correct.  The had root when I needed the local user.

which here might be `'C:\\home\\kolafsson\\.v....`